# toggle between views in drupal

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

I am using views to show some nodes data. currently I am showing 4 nodes at one time in a view... but customer need a toggle to view 1 node or 4 nodes... I need it Ajax based.

Any idea how to implement it or any direction??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create two views, one with 1 node and one with 4 nodes, then use the [Quick Tabs](http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs) module to toggle between the two views using Ajax.

You could also accomplish it with a single view with two different displays, then use the [Views Display Tabs](http://drupal.org/project/viewsdisplaytabs) module to do the Ajax toggling.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matt. I am also using Quick Tabs module for showing different views but i need the toggle inside a tab :)

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you need then. What mechanism do you want to use to trigger the toggling then? A form? A link?

Comment: Matt, I am able to set up the required thing... thanks a lot for your cooperation. only one thing is left. I've used Views Display Tabs, you mentioned, and now i need to put the tabs below the views contents(Bottom left corner). I am sure it is possible. Can I get any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add an exposed filter to the view and allow the customer to change the amount?  I'm sure if you set the view to use ajax the filter would be ajax based.

Comment: Hi Jamie, thanks for your post. Actually I am new to Drupal. May I know more about exposed filter? is this the filter used in views originally or something else like module?

Comment: It's a part of views.  On the bottom right when you edit the view, there is a box called filters.  You can add a filter and when you are adding it, there is a button that says "expose".  This enables users to be able to use a form called an "exposed filter".

Edit: On looking into this, it seems impossible to do.  Leave this with me and I'll find another way.  I may have to write a module for this.